# Tell Hibernate to only let the Database generate a value when it's null

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm implementing the PUT Methods for a REST-API.
I have a POJO similar to the following:

```
public class Brand implements Serializable {
    @Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
    @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Integer id;

    @Id
    @JsonProperty("brand")
    private String brand;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Within the postgresql database the brand table has the following columns:

- a database-internal id (SERIAL) which shall not be visible to the outside.(This is used manly for joining tables)
- a brand (TEXT) which is the primary key

My Service method looks like this:

```
public Brand updateBrand(String brand, Brand update) {
    Brand b = brandRepository.findBrandByBrand(brand);
    if(b == null) { //If not exists create new one
        b = new Brand(null, brand);
    }
    else {  //If exists keep id, delete old one and create new entry
        if(update != null && update.getBrand() != null) {
            brandRepository.delete(b);
        }
        ServiceUtils.copyProperties(update, b); //This is within the if clause, because brand is the only value
    }
    return brandRepository.save(b);
}
```

And the controller would have something like this:

```
@PutMapping(value = "/brand/{brand}")
public ResponseEntity<Brand> updateBrand(@PathVariable("brand") String brand,
                                         @RequestBody Brand update) {
    Brand updated = articleNumberService.updateBrand(brand, update);
    if(updated == null) {
        throw new EntryCreationFailedException(brand); //self made exception
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(updated, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Now my following problem is, that when calling PUT ../brand/stackoverflow
with body:

```
{"brand":"StackOverflow")
```

it deletes the old stackoverflow brand (which had id=1, for example) and creates a new one called StackOverflow. But when checking the database the id column is incremented (so now it has id=2).
I checked and this is caused by hibernate still calling:

```
insert 
    into
        brand
        (brand) 
    values
        (?)
```

This definitly is what I want when id is null. Which happens when creating a new Brand for example. But when only overriding the brand and id is not null I want hibernate to call this:

```
insert 
    into
        brand
        (id, brand) 
    values
        (?, ?)
```

I know this would be possible by creating a own save method and in an emergency override the query. BUT I'm quite optimistic that this should be possible without. Bt I can't realy find fitting answers to this. I already had problems finding the proper annotations for the postgresql-specific serial behavior.

P.S: I know that some will shout "why would you have Brand as the primary key and not id!?" But this only is a simple class/part of the database. There are more complex classes which use exactly the same way for the internal database id, (and actually need it), but have multiple primary keys etc. So this rather is a very simple representation for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Postgres use the serial as the auto_increment,  it's not included the id insertion in sql statement. Behind the scene,  it create the sequence for it.  So you should use the Generation type IDENTITY for it.

Comment: But where do I specify it? How I understood it, the @GeneratedValue Annotation is only for primary-keys?

Answer (score 0):

If it was a field with `@Id` you would be able to write a custom `@GenericGenerator` that fetched the sequence if the value was null, but as it's not a primary key, I think you would end up having to have a separate parent Entity with its own generated Id.